# create typeFace from byte array

Tags: android, fonts, arrays, typeface

In my app, I dynamically download fonts from server and save them to database. Is there any way how to create a Typaface from blob in db? Of course I can create temp file and load data from it, but it is not the best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the only way. You can create a Typeface from an asset file or a regular file. i would save the fonts on the device and store a path in the database. then just get the path out, create a File object, and create a Typeface.